# Import class to test model

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, phpunit, yii2-basic-app

I create UnitTest Class in dir /tests

[image: StationTest Hierachy]

Now I'd like to use class `Station` in test `StationsTest.php`.

```php
namespace app\Test;
namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use Codeception\PHPUnit\TestCase;
use app\models\Station;

class StationsTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreateStation()
    {
        $station = new Station();
        $station->name = 'TestName';
        $station->save();
    }
}
```

But when I run test:

```sh
vendor\bin\phpunit --verbose tests\StationsTest
```

I got error

```sh
Error: Class 'app\models\Station' not found
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How does your `phpunit.xml` (or) `phpunit.xml.dist` and `composer.json` looks like? You did not load the autoloader so PHP is unable to find the class.

Comment: The search finds many files with the same name. Where should be the right one?

Comment: In your project root directory, not inside the `vendor`'s dependencies directories.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you run the following command before launching test:

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

**and** that your `phpunit.xml.dist` has an entry like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit
        bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"

        [..] other properties
>
[..]
</phpunit>
```

Comment: The search finds many files with the same name. Where should be the right one?

Comment: Supposing that all your code is contained inside the `src/` folder and you have there your project's `src/composer.json`, the *right* autoload should be in `src/vendor/autoload.php`.